# Indefinite log retention on kafka

Tags: events, apache-kafka, event-sourcing

I am using kafka for event-sourcing. I realized that we still need to configure the log retention time, i.e. `log.retention.hours`.

What is the best value to use if I want to keep all my messages indefinitely? The sample configuration for `log.retention.bytes` is set to -1, can I use -1 also in the `log.retention.hours`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the following Kafka [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1990) which is due for the 0.9.0.0 release. For the time being set as suggested:

```
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.hours = 2147483647
```

Which is the same as forever (~250K years).

And then when the 0.9.0.0 release is available the `log.retention.hours` should have similar `-1` value available.